# Tracker issue database suggestion

Tags: database-design

Good morning everyone, i made this database i would like to know your opinions usertable and projecttable have a many to many relationship , ProjectCreatedByUser have two FKs (userID, projectID) , same for usertable and issuesID,IssueCreatedByUser have two FKS( IssueID and UserID) in every project it can have one or too many issues hence why i added projectID as a FK in the IssueTABLE
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check back on my comments to your three previous questions on designing an accounting application schema (avoid cross and or repeat-posting BTW).

Schema  design  is an [`iterative process`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative+process). There must be a billion issue tracker programmes out there - search for "[`open source issue/bug/ticket/problem tracker`](https://www.google.com/search?q=open%20source%20bug%20tracking%20software&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIE808IE808&oq=open%20source%20bug%20tracking%20software&aqs=chrome..69i57.9038j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" and you'll get loads of schemas with which to experiment.

Personal recommendation on this one, at least for initial study: [D. Richard Hipp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._Richard_Hipp)'s bug tracker called [Fossil](https://www.fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) - he uses an [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database to store the schema. From the Fossil site "Fossil is a simple, high-reliability, distributed software configuration management system" and the software that Hipp produces is stellar!

Look at those and then design your own schema. I don't know what development environment you're using, but take your first pass at a schema, and then run some code against it. Then fix the bugs (there **will** be bugs) and do the same thing again. Rinse and repeat until you get a programme that works to your own satisfaction.

If this is for some commercial need, then I suggest that you use an already available F/LOSS programme, unless your company has some compelling requirement that can only be fulfilled by a [COTS](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/COTS.html) product. You haven't mentioned any particular database server - that could be a factor in any choice of COTS and indeed F/LOSS. Some companies offer free products - Oracle has a bug tracker written in Apex for which the source is available and it's interface is very slick - your choices are virtually limitless in this domain.

If this is a school/uni project and your professor seems to enjoy handing out schema design projects (IMHO, a bookkeeping system is a bit much for a first project), then you should a) tell us this up front and b) show us that you have made some effort - which you have - your ERD above shows that you've at least thought about the problem.

Comment: thank you for your comment , i highly appreciate it , indeed its just a project that i'm doing to make my portfolio. i read that that database design is the important thing to have a great app thats why im trying to have a good database design for this project ,